# Delete file which matches a pattern using linux command

Tags: linux, bash

I have couple of questions regarding Linux commands:

1. I want to delete a directory and contents of that directory. My question is will the following command delete the `work` 
   directory and contents of that directory, or it will delete only contents of that directory?
   I searched internet and went through some forums but its not clear whether it will delete that directory or not. If it deletes
   only the contents then what is the command to delete that directory?

   **Command :**`rm -rf work`
2. Is the following command correct to delete all zip files inside `test` directory whose name starts with `Project`? I think `-r` is not
   required because it's a file. Please correct me if I am not wrong.

   **Command :** `rm -f test\Project*.zip`

Comment: Delete your question from StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548837/delete-file-which-matches-a-pattern-using-linux-command

Comment: This is really a trivial one, for 1) doing `rm -rf work` should work as expected and for 2) the slash should be `/` as `rm -f test/Project*.zip`

Comment: @Inian Consider answering the question with the information in your comment.

Comment: @Katu: I think its too trivial to answer, to be helpful in the community. Feel free to add so if you wish.

Comment: @Inian That's OK, I respect your opinion. Relevant meta question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209280/how-to-react-to-trivial-questions

Answer (score 1):

1. The command `rm -rf work` will delete both the directory and all its contents.  It does this by first deleting any files in the directory and if there are subdirectories, it recurses into them and deletes them in the same manner.  The empty `work` directory is deleted last.
2. The `-r` is not required.  The pathname is slightly wrong though since it seems to be using `\` as the path separator.  On Unix systems, `/` is the path separator.  To delete all files whose names start with `Project` and ends with `.zip` in the `test` directory, you do

   ```
   rm test/Project*.zip
   ```

   The `-f` is not needed either unless you have `rm` aliased to `rm -i` (which will make `rm` ask for confirmation before removing anything). In scripts, `-f` is often used to suppress error messages when deleting files that may not exist (`rm -f` will never fail even though the file may not exist). In interactive usage, `-f` is almost always used to override the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 0):

1 - `rm -rf work` deletes the directory and its contents. You can do `rm -rf work/*` if you wish to keep the dir and empty the contents.

2 - You are not wrong.

Also, why did you post a question here instead of trying for yourself, which would probably be way easier? Just curious.